# Custom Adapter for ListView in Fragment not working

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I have been trying to populate a listView in a fragment. I want it populated manually.

I have gone through so many other stackoverflow questions on the same topic but none of them have worked for me.

Here is my onCreateView in my fragment file
StoriesFragment.java

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stories, container, false);

    textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_textview);
    search = rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.short_story_list_view);
    username_textview = rootView.findViewById(R.id.username_textview);

    setHomeActivity();
        try {
        setUsername();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    shortStoryObject = homeActivity.getShortStoriesData();
    StoryAdapter adapter = new StoryAdapter(getActivity(), shortStoryObject);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}
```

Here is my adapter file. StoryAdapter.java

```
public class StoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShortStories> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ShortStories> shortStories;

    public StoryAdapter (Context mcontext, ArrayList<ShortStories> shortStories){
        super(mcontext, 0, shortStories);
        this.context = mcontext;
        this.shortStories = shortStories;
    }


@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView titleTextView, descriptionTextView, genreTextView, appCountTextView;

        ShortStories shortStories = getItem(position);


        titleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_title_textview);
        titleTextView.setText(shortStories.getShortTitle());

        descriptionTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_description_textview);
        descriptionTextView.setText(shortStories.getShortDescription());

        genreTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_genre_textview);
        genreTextView.setText(shortStories.getShortGenre());

        appCountTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_count_textview);
        appCountTextView.setText(shortStories.getAppCount());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is my listview file. list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:minHeight="170dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/lighterGrey"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/clown"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/short_title_textview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Jack The Ripper ooga booga boogaa" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/short_description_textview"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/short_title_textview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Jack The Ripper is totally badass amirite or amirite."/>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/genre"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="Genre: " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/short_genre_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/genre"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:text="Komedi" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/app_count_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_thumb_up_24"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/app_count_textview"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/app_count_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/status_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Status: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Completed"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my fragment layout. fragment_stories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/clown"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
                android:hint="Search">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:id="@+id/short_data_textview"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/short_story_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Here is the code for function getShortStories() from HomeActivity.

```
    public ArrayList<ShortStories> getShortStoriesData(){
    return shortStoryObject;
}
```

Here is an error logcat of the crash:

```
2021-04-06 12:09:17.442 29043-29043/? E/oid.air_storie: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2021-04-06 12:09:17.516 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.android.air_stories
2021-04-06 12:09:17.516 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-04-06 12:09:17.516 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.android.air_stories
2021-04-06 12:09:17.516 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-04-06 12:09:17.518 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: Fail to get file list oat
2021-04-06 12:09:17.518 29043-29076/com.example.android.air_stories E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: So what error do you get? Is there any exception or Just an empty list is shown?

Comment: Please add the code for this function `getShortStoriesData()`

Comment: @MayurGajra, The app crashes when listvew.setAdapter(adapter); runs. It works if I comment it but then of course the listview doesn't show in the app.

Comment: @IvanWooll I added the code for getShortStoriesData(). HomeActivity just returns that object wherever I call it into the fragment.

Comment: might be `shortStoryObject` is empty

Comment: @Kaushik, no it isn't. I extracted the data from the shortStoryObject and set the text in a Textview in the same fragment. Similary, listview and adapter aren't empty either. My guess is that it has something to do with the adapter not working correctly, because it only crashes when listview.setAdapter(adapter) is run.

Comment: then you should post the logcat of that crash otherwise we will keep guessing @RakayShahid

Comment: @Kaushik. I just added the error logcat of the crash.

Comment: It is clearly said that the array is null which you have used in adapter

Comment: @Kaushik. The Arraylist I'm passing to the adapter is not null. Like I said before, I have extracted data from it to set in a textview for testing purposes and it works then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it. I'm extremely dumb.

In the adapter file, StoryAdapter.java, I was setting the text from getAppCount() to a textview, while the function returns an integer and not a string. It worked when I converted it to string.

```
        appCountTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_count_textview);
    appCountTextView.setText("" + shortStories.getAppCount());
```